# String pattern matching in Swift switch statements

Tags: swift

I have a problem with pattern matching in swift switches. I need to check a string to see if it contains some characters and return data according to that.
I have the following (shortened) code:

```
static func getCorrectChords(chord: String) -> [Chord] {
    let test = chord
    switch test {
    case let x where x.contains("-") && x.contains("2"):
        return allChords[8]

    ///// other similar statements

    default:
        return allChords[0]
    }
}
```

If I pass the string “RE-2” to the function, it switch over all the statements and then goes with the default case. If I try a very similar code in Playgrounds, it works correctly.
Is there anything I’m doing wrong? How can I obtain the proper return value?

Thank you very much!

Edit: corrected braces and indentation in the code. Solution is now in the answers.

Comment: Playgrounds shouldn't have a different result. Is `allChords` the same?

Comment: Can't you just make `allChords` into a dictionary, such as `[ "RE-2": someChords , ...]`?

Comment: “If I try a very similar code in Playgrounds, it works correctly.” That means you did not isolate the problem when you put it in playgrounds. You removed the part of the code that causes the problem. Please isolate the problem and include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: The code you pasted doesn't have the correct number of braces and is indented strangely. Are you sure you shared all relevant code?

Comment: Hi everyone, sorry for not including all relevant information in the post, still trying to learn.
Anyway, I found the issue. As @Sweeper correctly pointed out, I did not isolate the problem correctly.
The issue was that my source data had a slightly different "-" character which Swift (rightly so) did not consider equal to the condition in the switch cases. I sanitized the inputs and now it works correctly. In the playground I did manually write the input so the issue did not arise.

Thank you so much anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I did not isolate the problem correctly.
The issue was that my source data had a slightly different "-" character which Swift (rightly so) did not consider equal to the condition in the switch cases. I sanitized the inputs and now it works correctly. In the playground I did manually write the input so the issue did not arise.

Thank you so much anyway!